# read_sf is truncating/rounding coordinates

Tags: r, sf, rgdal

I am using this function `read_sf` from package `sf` to read a shapefile in CRS 'ETRS89 / UTM zone 29N'. But coordinates are rounded to the meter after reading it.

Trying to make a reproducible example I have used 'ne_110m_admin_0_countries' from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/ I found that with this example data it works fine.

Why does it happens? Which is the difference?

```
shp_mydata <- read_sf(dsn="./layers", layer= 'mydata')
shp_nature <- read_sf(dsn="./layers", layer= 'ne_110m_admin_0_countries')

>   head(st_coordinates(shp_nature))
            X         Y L1 L2 L3
[1,] 180.0000 -16.06713  1  1  1
[2,] 180.0000 -16.55522  1  1  1
[3,] 179.3641 -16.80135  1  1  1
[4,] 178.7251 -17.01204  1  1  1
[5,] 178.5968 -16.63915  1  1  1
[6,] 179.0966 -16.43398  1  1  1

>   head(st_coordinates(shp_mydata))
            X       Y L1 L2
[1,] 758968.1 4154670  1  1
[2,] 758964.1 4154670  1  1
[3,] 758964.1 4154714  1  1
[4,] 758968.1 4154714  1  1
[5,] 758968.1 4154670  1  1
[6,] 758968.1 4154715  1  2
```

My data coordinates should something like this (screenshot from QGIS):

[image]

I need to read this layer in R to get the centroids of the polygons in a dataframe. My other approach would be calculate it in QGIS as fields and take the centroids coordinates from there but I want to avoid 'non-automatic' process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just related with how `head()` prints the output. I managed to reproduce the case but, using `paste()` shows other results.

```r
url <-
  "https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip"

tmpfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")

download.file(url, tmpfile)


unzip(tmpfile, list = TRUE)
#>                                    Name Length                Date
#> 1 ne_110m_admin_0_countries.README.html  23723 2018-05-21 00:28:00
#> 2 ne_110m_admin_0_countries.VERSION.txt      7 2018-05-21 00:28:00
#> 3         ne_110m_admin_0_countries.cpg      5 2018-05-21 00:24:00
#> 4         ne_110m_admin_0_countries.dbf 375450 2018-05-21 00:24:00
#> 5         ne_110m_admin_0_countries.prj    147 2018-05-21 00:24:00
#> 6         ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp 180924 2018-05-21 00:24:00
#> 7         ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shx   1516 2018-05-21 00:24:00

unzip(tmpfile, exdir = tempdir())

library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
#> Simple feature collection with 177 features and 94 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -180 ymin: -90 xmax: 180 ymax: 83.64513
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

head(st_coordinates(shp_nature))
#>             X         Y L1 L2 L3
#> [1,] 180.0000 -16.06713  1  1  1
#> [2,] 180.0000 -16.55522  1  1  1
#> [3,] 179.3641 -16.80135  1  1  1
#> [4,] 178.7251 -17.01204  1  1  1
#> [5,] 178.5968 -16.63915  1  1  1
#> [6,] 179.0966 -16.43398  1  1  1

# Reproducing the issue
head(st_coordinates(st_transform(shp_nature, 25829)))
#>              X         Y L1 L2 L3
#> [1,] -465991.8 -18198445  1  1  1
#> [2,] -463564.4 -18143886  1  1  1
#> [3,] -393903.2 -18119393  1  1  1
#> [4,] -324312.9 -18098713  1  1  1
#> [5,] -312167.7 -18140810  1  1  1
#> [6,] -366815.6 -18161578  1  1  1

# Checking  with paste - See the precision
paste(head(st_coordinates(st_transform(shp_nature, 25829))))
#>  [1] "-465991.750691513" "-463564.440265044" "-393903.162080466"
#>  [4] "-324312.903355739" "-312167.687133071" "-366815.640994568"
#>  [7] "-18198445.2823013" "-18143885.6669874" "-18119393.0910158"
#> [10] "-18098713.3859035" "-18140810.39632"   "-18161577.9241656"
#> [13] "1"                 "1"                 "1"                
#> [16] "1"                 "1"                 "1"                
#> [19] "1"                 "1"                 "1"                
#> [22] "1"                 "1"                 "1"                
#> [25] "1"                 "1"                 "1"                
#> [28] "1"                 "1"                 "1"
```

You can check visually with:

```r
# Visual inspection - Check
check <- st_coordinates(st_transform(shp_nature, 25829))
View(check)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Indeed, even checking visually the data the coordinates are shown rounded, but when used for any calculation e.g. distances to a point. The 'complete/real' coordinate with precision is taken into account. Thank you!